# Best way to allow user to create a table

Tags: website-design, usability, forms, layout

What's a good way to allow users to create a table? Originally, I was thinking markdown, but I'd really like something simpler.

One idea I had:

[image]

Comment: what is a purpose of table?

Answer (score 2):

main problem I see with your version, it's not clear what value goes into which cell.

have you thought of something more interactive?

1. either via drag and drop (you increase the number of columns or rows when you drag past a certain threshold: for example every 30px dragged down you add a new row); this could be harder to implement
2. create a default 3x2 table with buttons for delete and add columns and rows

in both cases you would have a placeholder text in each cell which becomes an editable input when clicked.